# VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER in virtualbox after hard reset

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I had to hard reset my notebook after my system (Ubuntu gnome 15.04) freezes. Now I'm not able to resume the vagrant and if I try to load it on virtualbox I receive this message:

```
Could not open the medium '/home/stsmuniz/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_default_1441759013197_1623/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VMDK: inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table in '/home/stsmuniz/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_default_1441759013197_1623/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/home/stsmuniz/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_default_1441759013197_1623/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).


Código de Resultado: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Componente:
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

Can anybody help me on solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with a corrupt vmdk disk. It is discussed briefly [on the Whonix troubleshooting page](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#INCONSISTENCY_BETWEEN_GRAIN_TABLE_AND_BACKUP_GRAIN_TABLE).

To fix it, the idea is to convert the vmdk disk into a vdi disk, unmount the old vmdk disk from the VM and attach in its stead the newly minted vdi disk.

Tools to do that are discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/324271/virtualbox-grain-table-inconsistency) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/940300/can-i-fix-corrupted-vmdk-image-verr-vd-vmdk-invalid-header).

Comment: I did the steps shown [here](https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2009/03/22/how-to-convert-vmware-image-vmdk-to-virtualbox-image-vdi/) and after converting the box to VDI it worked.

Thank you, buddy.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on macos x sierra running vagrant ubuntu box.
it happend when the guest box was frozen due to pg_restore process

had to download the homebrew then install qemu using brew

and followed the instructions on

https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2009/03/22/how-to-convert-vmware-image-vmdk-to-virtualbox-image-vdi/

then edit the vbox file to change the uuid and location to point to the newly created vdi file

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.