# Power Outage: Corrupted vmdk image - VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER

Tags: virtualbox, power, headers, vmdk

I read a similar thread on this site

[Can I fix corrupted vmdk image? VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER](https://superuser.com/questions/940300/can-i-fix-corrupted-vmdk-image-verr-vd-vmdk-invalid-header/1027220#1027220)

but I need more assistance on the steps to try and make this repair.

I have the exact problem that Pierrick on that thread.

Everyone had an answer of VDDK or vdiskmanager... Could someone provide basic instructions on how to use these? I am running windows 8 so I'm not sure if these can be ran on that.

I downloaded VDDK and unzipped it and I'm lost from there.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had to download the VDDK from https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/65/vddk then navigate to the folder containing my vmdk and run (in a terminal):

```
sudo <path-to-vdiskmanager>/vmware-vdiskmanager -R <name-of-vmdk>.vmdk
```

If the repair is successful, you should see:

```
The virtual disk, '<name-of-vmdk>.vmdk', was corrupted and has been successfully repaired.
```

We also had released the box from within the VirtualBox UI and so had to reattach it with:

```
VBoxManage storageattach <name-of-box> --medium "<path-to-vmdk>.vmdk" --storagectl "SATA" --device 0 --port 0 --type hdd
```